# Need help finding a plus sign using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the code below to find a match for a plus sign but it keeps returning false. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be really appreciated it. Thanks!

```
 var str = '+2443';
var result = /d\+1/.test(str);
console.log(result); // true
```

Comment: Your regex matches a literal `d`, followed by a literal `+`, followed by a literal `1`, which is `d+1`. Of course, this doesn’t match `+2443`. Have you tried understanding what the regex means with tools like [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/KTCnJQ/1)?

Comment: You are right. I should of thought about it first. I copied it paste it from google. I just read about it, and made it work with

var result = /\+/.test(str);

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str = '+2443';
var result = /\+/.test(str);
console.log(result); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `/d\+1/` regex matches the first occurrence of a `d+1` substring in any string.

To check if a string contains a `+`, you do not need a regex. Use `indexOf`:

```js
var str = '+2443';
if (~str.indexOf("+")) {
 console.log("Found a `+`");
} else  {
 console.log("A `+` is not found");
}
```

A regex will be more appropriate when you need to match a `+` in some context.  For example, to check if the string starts with a plus, and then only contains digits, you would use

```js
var str = '+2443';
var rx = /^\+\d+$/;
console.log(rx.test(str));
```

where `^` assets the position at the end of the string, `\+` matches a literal `+`, `\d+` matches 1+ digits and the `$` anchor asserts the position at the end of the string.